# Singleton using getInstance vs public declaration

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, singleton

What's the point in creating `getInstance()` when you can just make the variable public and access the instance?

I am aware of the abstract factory design pattern which makes sense with factories since we decide on run-time the kind of implementation we need.

**Using getInstance():**

```
public class ClientFactory {
    private static ClientFactory instance = null;

    private ClientFactory() { }

    public static synchronized ClientFactory getInstance() {
        if ( instance == null ) {
            instance = new ClientFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

**Making variable public instead of creating instance method:**

```
 public class ClientFactory {
    public static final ClientFactory instance = new ClientFactory ();
    private ClientFactory() { }
 }
```

and we can easily get the accesses using `ClientFactory.instance.foo();`.

Comment: What if some other class creates new instance? `ClientFactory.instance = new ClientFactory();` Moreover what if some class assignes to instance some derived class from ClientFactory? `ClientFactory.instance = new DerivedClientFactory();`

Comment: they cannot, constructor is private.

Comment: Ah, my bad...did not notice

Comment: If you go with the public field, at least make it `final` (so that no one can mess with it).

Comment: @Thilo yes, i missed that. it's with `final`

Answer (score 1):

The latter example is eager - `ClientFactory` is always created. It can be a drawback, when there is a low possibility, that `ClientFactory` will be used and instantiation of it is costly.

The first one is lazy. That means, that when `ClientFactory` is not used, it's not being created at all. Besides `ClientFactory` is immutable, whereas a public field can be overwritten. Its instantiation is also safe because it's guarded by `synchronized`.

With that safety consider a situation, when client invokes the following line (in the first case):

```
ClientFactory.instance = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using FactoryMethod like `getInstance()` gives you more options for future changes.

E.g.

- Lazy loading
- Replacing the actual class with one of its proxy
- Replacing class with one of its children (if one day `ClientFactory` evolve into abstract classes with different child implementation), etc.

Comment: Yes, that's very much the advantage of abstraction but why should we be creating it when we know a service and it will behave exactly in one way.

Comment: Option for future changes is all about being able to adapt to when the things you know are no longer true. Requirements change, software evolves. FWIW both patterns are kind of old school and many people replace them with dependency injection. Then the code that uses your service does not need to care where it came from.

Comment: @Thilo true but that's a minute change. I mean when I get the requirements, I can make it more loosely coupled and modular.

Comment: Fair enough. But the answer still stands: Using a function provides the option to later change the implementation without needing the update all callers. A field cannot do that. If you need that or not is up to you.

Comment: cool, thanks @Thilo moreover the difference of eager initialization and lazy stands there as well and yes that's on lower level

Answer (score 1):

As others correctly pointed out main difference between those two appraches is that first approach will use lazy instantiation whereas in second one the object is created eagerly. The `ClientFactory` field in the second apprach should be marked `final` to avoid letting clients of this class to reaasign this field.

Also the first approach uses `synchronized` which might have performance impact because after the field is assigned successfully for the first time - there is no need for synchronization later. Therefor instead fo this approach you could also use [`initialization-on-demand`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) with holder instance (since you are using a static field for your singleton):

```
public class ClientFactory {

    private ClientFactory() { }

    private static class ClientFactoryHolder {
        private static final ClientFactory INSTANCE = new ClientFactory();
    }

    public static ClientFactory getInstance() {
        return ClientFactoryHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

it makes use of JVM class initialization. The `ClientFactoryHolder.INSTANCE` field  will be **only** initialized if someone invokes `ClientFactory.getInstance` method since class will be initialized when it is first referenced. Also notice that now `getInstance` method does not have to be synchronized since JVM takes care of it for us.